# MAUI project, cannot add a new Page

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, maui

I'm trying out MAUI and I've ran into a weird bug. It won't let me add a new Page, every time i try to do so the `InitializeComponent` in the constructor gives me an error :

> The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context

I've added `Microsoft.Maui.Controls` in the C# code and in the XAML code.

```
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
```

Does anyone know what to do here?

[image]

[image: Error message]

Comment: Where did you add the page? In a subfolder or anything? Also what VS and .NET 6 version are you using?

Comment: What steps did you do, to create the page? Assuming this behaves the same as Xamarin Forms, usually that error means the xaml is not in same namespace as the .xaml.cs. Show the declation lines at start of xaml. Especially the class attribute, and any namespace declaration used in that. A rarer possibility is a problem with the build setting on one of those two source files.

Comment: Also, have you BUILT the project, after adding the page? If not, its merely an Intellisense glitch. will go away after a successful build. Comment out any incomplete code elsewhere, if that interferes with successful build.

Comment: I'm using visual studio 2022 preview and .NET 6.0.100-preview-6-21355.2. I've tried to build the solution but im still stuck with the same error. I added the page on the same level as App.cs and MainPage.cs. The steps I took as the same steps I've done when I've created a new page using xamarin.forms, which is right-click -> add new item -> Content Page.

Comment: this is the declation lines at start of xaml:  `code` <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MealTime.Page1">
    <ContentPage.Content>
       
            <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
       
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>`code`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I got the same error after adding new MAUI page to the project. The solution was to remove the following lines from `.csproj` file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <MauiXaml Remove="Pages\Page1.xaml" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <EmbeddedResource Include="Pages\Page1.xaml">
    <Generator>MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml</Generator>
  </EmbeddedResource>
</ItemGroup>
```

Then remove `InitializeComponent();` statement in `Page1.xaml.cs` file, rebuild the project and finally add `InitializeComponent();` back to `Page1.xaml.cs`.

The problem is that Maui SourceGen was not able to generate `Page1.xaml.sg.cs` file for the `Page1.xaml.cs` file.

Let me know if this solution works for you.

Comment: It worked! Thank you! But now the page.xaml and the page.xaml.cs are not merged in the solution but i guess thats just a bug for now maybe

Comment: and I can't navigateto the newley added page

Comment: This might be bug that they are not merged, it is true.

@CodeBuddyBenny Regarding navigation. I need to see a code and try it my selv. Can you create a new question with code example and share a link to me. I will take a look.

Comment: In VS 17.1.0, it worked for me after just removing the indicated lines from the `.csproj` file. Removing and readding `InitializeComponent();` was not necessary.

Comment: @CodeBuddyBenny: It was the same for me, but when I unloaded and reloaded the project, the files were nested as usual.

Comment: This worked for me.  In my .csproj file, the MauiXaml Remove line and the EmbeddedResource block was under a comment line "<!-- Raw Assets (also remove the "Resources\Raw" prefix) -->".  I have no idea what I did to the XAML to make it create that XML in the .csproj file.

Comment: Exclude from project \ Add existing item (just excluded) - helps

Answer (score 5):

This is already answerd but found this .In Microsoft Visual Studio Community

```
2022 (64-bit) - Preview
Version 17.1.0 Preview 1.1
```

. I added this

```
.NET MAUI Project and Item Templates from Visual Studio Marketplace
```

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=egvijayanand.maui-item-templates

Then like normal add....and select MAUI

[image]

Comment: page not found.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above answers.  If you are still having a problem (app crashing on going to the page and no other information.  Then try this:

```
namespace DeviceFinder;

public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(DetailsPage), typeof(DetailsPage));
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(SettingsPage), typeof(SettingsPage));
        // Specifically, this above line you have to manually add in ^^^
    }
}
```

In your code-behind of AppShell.XAML you have to register the route.  Who knows why... but it works.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was creating 2 files: `NewPage1.cs` and `NewPage1.xaml`

I needed to rename `NewPage1.cs` to `NewPage1.xaml.cs`.

Theres 2 hours of my life I'll never get back.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the namespace within my .cs file and my xaml.cs file did not match.

Setting the namespaces to match fixed it. Here is the fixed example:

```
// from the cs xaml.cs file:

namespace MauiApp2;

public partial class EventDetailsPage : ContentPage
...
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    x:Class=" MauiApp2.EventDetailsPage"
...
```

The x:Class setting was not correct and after fixing the error was resolved.