# Error CS0103 The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context in project upgrade from xamarin.forms to .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, maui, .net-8.0

I am in the process of updating my Xamarin.Forms project to .NET MAUI and am encountering the error

> Error CS0103: The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context.

The problem appears to be that Maui SourceGen was unable to generate the xaml.sg.cs file for the xaml.cs file.

I have noticed that topic [MAUI project, cannot add a new Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68639893/maui-project-cannot-add-a-new-page) and topic [.NET MAUI: The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74601011/net-maui-the-name-initializecomponent-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context) discuss this subject, but following the responses provided there, none have resolved my issue, which I find peculiar.

I created a new Maui content page in the following manner.
[image]

The file xaml is structured as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Ren9ve.ERP.Mobile.NewPage1"
             Title="NewPage1">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label 
            Text="Welcome to .NET MAUI!"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

And the xaml.cs file.

```
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls;

namespace Ren9ve.ERP.Mobile
{
    public partial class NewPage1 : ContentPage
    {
        public NewPage1()
        {
            //Here is where the reported error occurs.
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

In the .csproj file, it is set up as follows.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <MauiXaml Update="NewPage1.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </MauiXaml>
  </ItemGroup>
```

If I create a new Maui project in the same solution and create an identical file, it works normally. The error only occurs in the project that I am updating to Maui. The error occurs in all XAML files, but for testing purposes, I commented out all the CS0103 errors and left only the one from the new file.

I'm using VS2022 17.8.4

1. I have set the build action for the C# file to C# Compiler
2. I have cleaned and rebuilt my project several times and tried
   deleting the bin and obj folders, but nothing seems to work
3. I attempted to test on a different machine.
4. I compared the csproj with one from a new Maui project but didn't find anything that could cause the issue.
5. I tried implementing solution [MAUI project, cannot add a new Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68639893/maui-project-cannot-add-a-new-page) but it also did not work.

Comment: I'm wondering if fully qualifying that tag in the .csproj might help. `<MauiXaml Update="Ren9ve.ERP.Mobile.NewPage1">`

Comment: `I have set the build action for the C# file to C# Compiler` The Build Action for your XAML file should be MauiXaml

Comment: I tested by adding <MauiXaml Update="Ren9ve.ERP.Mobile.NewPage1">, but it did not work.

I am aware that the Build Action of the XAML should be MauiXaml; I only changed the .cs file for testing purposes, but then reverted it back to the standard.

Comment: Have you followed the official document  [Upgrade from Xamarin to .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/?view=net-maui-8.0)?

Comment: yes, I followed and also used the .NET Upgrade Assistant

Comment: How can we reproduce this problem? Could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem?